# Simple way to estimate the root of $x^5-x^ 4+2x^3+x^2+x+1=0$

Tags: complex-numbers, numerical-methods

How to give a mathematical proof that for all complex roots of $x^5-x^ 4+2x^3+x^2+x+1=0$, their real part is smaller than 1, and there is at least one root whose real part is larger than 0. If possible, not to solve any algebraic equation whose degree is larger than 3.

For the real roots, it would be easy to estimate them by observing the derivative and intermediate value theorem. What about the complex roots? I fail to find a way by trying Rouché's theorem.

Comment: Some ideas are given in [properties of polynomial roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Properties_of_polynomial_roots), and [Descartes' rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes'_rule_of_signs) helps bound the number of real (positive and negative) zeros.

Comment: You can use the [Hurwitz staility criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routh%E2%80%93Hurwitz_stability_criterion) (with a little trick). I'll write a complete answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Routh-Hurwitz stability criterion](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Control_Systems/Routh-Hurwitz_Criterion) you can tell how may roots of your system are in the open left-hand complex plane - i.e., the set $\{z\in\mathbb{C}: \operatorname{Re}(z) < 0\}$.

In your case for the polynomial $p(x)=x^5 - x^4 + 2x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$ the Hurwitz matrix is:

```
    1.0000    2.0000    1.0000
   -1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
    3.0000    2.0000         0
    1.6667    1.0000         0
    0.2000         0         0
    1.0000         0         0
```

Indeed, there are two roots with nonnegative real part. We can verify that there are no imaginary roots simply by replacing $x=ic$ and try to determine $c\in\mathbb{R}$ so that $p(x)=0$.

Now, in order to determine whether all roots have a real part which is lower than $1$ we need to apply the Hurwitz criterion to the polynomial $q(x) = p(x+1)$. In fact, this is

$$
q(x) = p(x+1) = x^5 + 4x^4 + 8x^3 + 11x^2 + 10x + 5
$$

for which the Hurwitz matrix is

```
1.0000    8.0000   10.0000
4.0000   11.0000    5.0000
5.2500    8.7500         0
4.3333    5.0000         0
2.6923         0         0
5.0000         0         0
```

therefore all roots of $q$ are in the open left-hand plane, thus all roots of $p$ have real parts which are smaller than $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Since we have the time, consider first [numerical approximations](http://www.akiti.ca/PolyRootRe.html) of the roots to verify that the claim is likely true:

```
-0.030123633319861776   +   0.7941475177755543 i
-0.030123633319861776   -   0.7941475177755543 i
-0.6325536017497507
 0.8464004341947371   +   1.3366723150584239 i
 0.8464004341947371   -   1.3366723150584239 i
```

so you have 3 roots with negative real part, and two with positive real part smaller 1.

---

The half plane left of the line $Re(z)=1$ is given by the equation $|\frac{z}{z-2}|<1$, or in general of points where the distance to $1-a$ is smaller than the distance to $1+a$ for some $a>0$.

Set $w=\frac{z}{z-2}$, then $z=\frac{2w}{w-1}$ and 
$$
g(w)=(w-1)^5f(\tfrac{2w}{w-1})=39w^5 - 41w^4 + 50w^3 - 22w^2 + 7w - 1
$$
Now all that remains is to prove that the root radius of this polynomial is smaller than $1$. This can be done via 2 Dandelin-Graeffe iterations giving 
$$
g_1(x^2)=g(x)g(-x),\; g_1(x)=-1521w^5 - 2219w^4 - 1242w^3 - 134w^2 - 5w + 1\\
g_2(x^2)=g_1(x)g_1(-x)\; g_2(x)=-2313441w^5 + 1145797w^4 - 963082w^3 + 1098w^2 - 293w + 1
$$
where now Rouche can be applied. However, that is not very friendly for manual computations.

---

From the numerical solutions it is visible that two roots should be in the half plane $Re(z)>1/2$. Using $w=\frac{z-1}z$ this translates to the points where $|w|<1$. Using $z=\frac1{1-w}$ gives
$$
g(w)=(1-w)^5f(\tfrac{1}{1-w})=-w^5 + 6w^4 - 15w^3 + 21w^2 - 15w + 5
$$
and one Dandelin-Graeffe iteration gives 
$$
g_1(x^2)=g(x)g(-x),\; g_1(x)=-w^5 + 6w^4 - 3w^3 + 51w^2 - 15w + 25
$$
which again allows to apply the Rouche theorem, even if barely.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial solution.  I don't have any good idea for the first part of the question (showing the real parts of the roots are all smaller than $1$), but the second part is easy:  The sum of the roots is $1$, i.e., the negative of the coefficient of $x^4$, which is impossible if the roots' real parts are all non-positive.  So at least one root has a postive real part.